# Goodness of fit in terms of distributions for mixed-effects GLMs

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, goodness-of-fit, discrete-data

I am using a generalized linear mixed-effects model to predict the rate of events generated by a collection of different sources over time. The response variable is the number of events by source by day. I would like to compare goodness of fit for alternative model structures and present the metric used in accessible way to non-technical audience. Since the rates of events vary greatly, standard predicted value-oriented goodness of fit metrics (such as RMSE, MAD, MAPE) don't work very well for this use case. **Are there any goodness of fit metrics in terms of distributions that are easy to present and that can be applied to mixed-effects GLMs?**

Comment: How is goodness of fit is not a data science topic?

Comment: Because goodness-of-fit for GLMs is basic statistics. Maybe there's someone here on DS that can answer it, but the evidence of the answers I've seen mean that's unlikely. Machine learning, big data, yeah, but GoF diagnostics? There's several thousand more competent statisticians on CrossValidated than here. Please try it.

Comment: I think this kind of question is on-topic for both SEs. They do overlap somewhat. I wouldn't cross-post, but I also wouldn't migrate this necessarily.